# How to create a 2D array of Strings in Julia

Tags: arrays, matrix, julia

How to create a 2D (9 by 9) array of Strings in Julia and initialize it

```
global AStrings = String(9,9)
```

Then assign a float64 , float64 to it

```
AStrings[i,j] =  string(c[i]) * "," * string(c2[i])
```

Note `c[i]` and `c2[i]` are two float numbers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`String(9,9)` is not a method in Julia. Type `?String` in the REPL to get help with a function. The `$` as I used it below is called [string interpolation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/strings/#string-interpolation). It is useful for constructing strings using other types, though what you wrote would also work. When typing code on forums like this, type ``` before and after the code so that it will be formatted nicely like mine.

```
julia> A = fill("", 9, 9)
9×9 Matrix{String}:
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""

julia> x = 3.2
3.2

julia> y = 5.7
5.7

julia> A[2,3] = "$x, $y"
"3.2, 5.7"

julia> A
9×9 Matrix{String}:
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  "3.2, 5.7"  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
 ""  ""  ""          ""  ""  ""  ""  ""  ""
```

Answer (score 6):

You can avoid the headache of working out how to correctly instantiate an array by just using a comprehension:

```
julia> c = round.(rand(3), digits = 2); c2 = round.(rand(3), digits = 2);

julia> ["$x,$y" for x ∈ c, y ∈ c2]
3×3 Matrix{String}:
 "0.2,0.21"   "0.2,0.98"   "0.2,0.04"
 "0.32,0.21"  "0.32,0.98"  "0.32,0.04"
 "0.29,0.21"  "0.29,0.98"  "0.29,0.04"
```

If you really do want to instantiate an "empty" array, you can do it like this:

```
julia> Matrix{String}(undef, 3, 3)
3×3 Matrix{String}:
 #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef
 #undef  #undef  #undef
```

Note that the type of the object I'm creating is `Matrix{String}` (which is the same as `Array{String, 2}`, not `String` (which is the element type of the array)